# SuiteScript to sum the weight based on ship-out location

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I want to be able to calculate the total weights of the items on the sales order based on their ship-out locations and store the values in custom fields. I created a before submitting script on this. The custom field is set to decimal number type and the store value box is checked, but nothing shows up under the field on sales order page.

```
function calculateWeight(type){

  var lines = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');

  var totalWeight2 = 0 ;
  var totalWeight1 = 0 ;

  if (lines >0){
      for(var i = 1; i<= lines ; i++){
          var location = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','location', i);
          var quantitycommitted = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','quantitycommitted', i);
          var weight = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','custcol_individual_weight', i);
          //var com_wgt = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','custcol1',i);

          if (location === '2'){
              var total2 = weight * quantitycommitted;

              totalWeight2 += total2 ;
          }

          if (location === '1'){
              var total1 = weight * quantitycommitted;

              totalWeight1 += total1 ;
          }

      }

      nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody5', totalWeight1);
      nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody4', totalWeight2);

  }

}
```

I am still learning SuiteScript and I am not exactly sure where went wrong... Can somebody help?

---

Updated code, only worked for some of the orders...

```
function calculateWeight(type){

  var lines = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
  //nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Number of lines', lines);

  var totalWeight2 = 0 ;
  var totalWeight1 = 0 ;

  if (lines >0){
      for(var i = 1; i<= lines ; i++){
      var location = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','location', i);
    //nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Locations', location);
      var quantitycommitted = parseInt(nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','quantitycommitted', i),10) || 0;
    //nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'QtyCom', quantitycommitted);
      var weight = parseFloat(nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','custcol_individual_weight', i)) ||0;
     //nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Wgt', weight);

    //var com_wgt = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','custcol1',i);

      if (location == '2'){
          var total2 = weight * quantitycommitted;

          totalWeight2 += total2 ;
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Total2', totalWeight2);

      }

      if (location == '1'){
          var total1 = weight * quantitycommitted;

          totalWeight1 += total1 ;
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Total1', totalWeight1);
      }

  }

  nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_ms_weight_ppt_page', totalWeight1);
  nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_wi_weight_ppt_page', totalWeight2);

 }

}
```

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on SuiteScript 1.0, but you may have to load the context to access the record using `nlapiGetContext()`.  I'd suggest logging a few of your variables to make sure they're returning the values you expect - for example `nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Number of lines', lines);` after `var lines = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');` - if that returns `-1` it means it's not looking at the actual record.

Comment: Hi again @Krypton! :D I logged all the variables, they all have the correct values and I didn't use the nlapiGetContext(). I made changes to my code according to the answer below and it worked; however, it seems like the script only applies to sales orders that are created/modified after the script is run, rather than to all the sales orders that already exist... Do you have any idea what happened...?

Comment: beforeSubmit user events are only triggered on write operation types as listed in [SuiteAnswer 10635](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10635).  So one of those events needs to be triggered for the script to run.  If you want to apply those changes to all existing sales orders, you will probably need to write a scheduled or map/reduce script.  You can set it up so that the [scheduled script triggers the user event](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45639/kw/trigger%20user%20event%20from%20scheduled) if that applies - this will save rewriting the logic.

Comment: I see... I will check the scheduled/map/reduce script! Thank you sooo much for the idea!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the line values:

```
var quantitycommitted = parseInt(nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','quantitycommitted', i),10) || 0;
var weight = parseFloat(nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','custcol_individual_weight', i)) ||0;
```

also in some contexts your location ids will not be strings so that may also be the issue. Relying on `==` instead of `===` works.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I think it's working! However, it seems like that the script doesn't populate the fields on all the existing orders. It only works when I create a new order or edit+save an existing order. Is this because I am using the before submitting event...? Is there a way to have the script populate the fields for all the existing orders as well?

Comment: You'd have to use the code in a mass update script or export your sales orders to a spreadsheet; do a calc and re-import;

IMO the mass update script is easier.

Comment: You can also just do an export where the values are blank and then import changing any value (I have historically set a period at the end of a memo field for this). If you turn on "run server suitescripts" during the import then your script will fire on those orders. This may be easier than doing the calculations in Excel or writing a separate script that will only be run once. Leverage what you built!

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I'd forgotten that I have also done the same thing with a mass update script with the same idea.

Comment: bknights and @TMann Thank you for the suggestions I will try that! There is another problem that I found after running the script for a couple of days. Even when all the variables are greater than zero, it still shows 0s for the total weights (totalWeight1 and totalWeight2). We are using the auto-location assignment, is it because of the script is running before locations are assigned?

Comment: that's entirely possible. You can change the order of your scripts using the Scripted Records dialog.